# How to use dependency injection in validator constraints with Doctrine & Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony5

I'm working on an platform which contains lot of page with form and i'm looking for a way to inject (DI) service in my Entity/Constraint Validator.
I tried many way, but never managed to do 100% what i wanted it.

Let me explain en detail :
my stack : Php 8.0, Symfony 5.4, Doctrine 2

To make it simple, i will take the example of `create page` Form.

The form is build with a dedicated FormType (let's say `DogType`).
The Entiy related to this FormType is `Dog`
I'm using static loader to load constraints `loadValidatorMetadata()`

The field `dog_race` has a constraint `ChoiceType`.
The data of choice should be filled with a method from a service `AnimalManager`, method `getRaces`. The constructor of this service is also using DI to get some other service such as `Logger` etc.

So, i know we can do something like that :

```php
public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
{
    [...]
    $metadata->addPropertyConstraints('dog_race',
        [
            new Assert\Choice([
                'callback' => [DogManager::class, 'getRaces'],
                'message'  => 'doc.incorrect_race'
            ])
        ]
    )
}
```

But this callback works only with static method.
If i'm not mistaken, we can use only `static loader`, `php attribut` and `annotation`, right ?
But in all cases, i don't see how i can inject a service for the constraint.

My question is, how can i inject my service DogManager to be used in the constraint ?
If not possible, any recommendation/alternative to do something similar ?

I have the feeling i have to create custom constraint just to be able to inject my service.. :(

Thanks

Comment: Your feeling is right.  You need a custom validator.  The docs will walk your through with the details.  It may seem a bit painful but once you get the first one working then it becomes easy.

Comment: Same advice, it's not surprising to use a custom validator in this case and it's easy and fast to implement once you get the hang of it. You could either use a class validator and check your whole entity or use customs property constraints with field like dogRace.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html

Comment: ok, i will some test with custom constraint so.

thanks for your answer :)